# Is loading SVG code into HTML unoptimized or slow compared to IMG tag?

Tags: html, css, svg

A simple rule for web I've been adopting lately: keep the DOM minimal. 
I'm trying to insert fewest elements possible in the DOM, but now I have to insert some SVG images (about 30).

Currently they are being loaded into an img tag, but I would like to insert them inside the code itself, so I can customize some colors with classes.

Taking a look at the SVG code, though, I've seen a lot of tags. Which, correct me if I'm wrong, would become DOM elements.

My question is, would loading the code directly inside my HTML make my page much heavier compared to loading as external image? How can I test my "code / DOM weight" to compare and benchmark this?

Comment: Even when you do load svg images into an img, the browser has to parse its markup just like if it weren't in one. (Well actually with some more constraints in the parsing). So while yes, appending it directly will make your current DOM heavier, loading it through an img tag will just create an other DOM only for this img. But anyway, except if your svg has more than tenth of thousands elements, most modern devices and browsers will handle it just right.

Comment: You can't access the DOM of an image. The DOM "weight" is the same though. There's no way to tell that except to ask an browser implementor, fortunately I just told you so know you know.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, yes. SVG can be verbose and, therefore, weigh down a page. However, comparing SVG to an actual image is a balancing act between image size and how you want to manipulate the image as you indicate.

As always, the only way to know for sure is to measure and test.

But how are you going to manipulate the color of an image? SVG will be most likely far easier to do and, perhaps, difficult or impossible with a png or jpg. So the decision may already be made for you.

Comment: any ideas on how to test the dom weight?

Comment: OP is aksing between inline HTMLSVG vs loaded SVG document. The comparison with raster images is not relevant here.